# animate object shaped with curves modifier by moving curve vertex

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

So I created this beaded bracelet and want to know if it possible to animate the path so it looks like it is "wiggling" (ideally grab two opposite vertices and move them around.) 
Since it is a nurbspath I cannot parent, and using a curves modifier and then changing the path  doesn't seem to do anything. 
The string and beads are a joined object with a curves modifier already applied for this initial shape. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ray Mairlot says, you can hook your vertices to empties, you can also hook them to bones (which, contrary to empties, would allow you to have a *Rest* pose). In my opinion, converting your nurb to a bezier will make things easier (*Curve > Set Spline Type > Bezier*).

- Create your armature with as many bones as you have vertices in your curve. Put them over those vertices.
- Switch your armature to *Pose* mode, select the bone you want.
- Shift select the curve, go in *Edit* mode, select the vertex that is supposed to be controlled by this bone.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to Selected Bone*.
- Now you can animate your curve.